# How do I get the current location of bar in scroll bar?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollbar

#### Overview:

Consider the following image:

[image: My Screenshot]

There is a vertical scrollbar and a horizontal scrollbar. After clicking on <kbd>OK</kbd>, the frame would disappear.

After some other works, I want to leave the user at the same position as it is now, which may be in different image with having same width and height. So, I want to keep track of the bars in scroll bars.

#### Question:

- Is there any built-in function to get the percentage or something to `get` and `set` the bar position?

  - If yes, what are they?
  - If no, what is the way to handle it?

#### Code:

*MultipleProcess.java* class, which actually opens the frame.

```
// imports and package description were here

public class MultipleProcess extends javax.swing.JDialog {
    SinglePaperEvaluation upperClass;
    BatchPaperEvaluation upperClass2;
    File imageFilePath;
    BufferedImage image;

    public MultipleProcess(boolean modal,File imageFile,SinglePaperEvaluation upper, BatchPaperEvaluation upper2) {
        super(upper==null?upper2:upper,"Co-ordinate Detector", modal);
        initComponents();
        upperClass = upper;
        upperClass2 = upper2;
        imageFilePath = imageFile;

        //adjust screen and windows listener were here

        loadImage();//custom function, it loads image in the jScrollPaneImageScreen

        if(upperClass2!=null){
            upperClass2.setVisible(false);

            //scrollbars states loading part
            jScrollPaneImageScreen.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(upperClass2.verticalBar);
            jScrollPaneImageScreen.getHorizontalScrollBar().setValue(upperClass2.horizontalBar);
//            if(upperClass2.react!=null)jScrollPaneImageScreen.scrollRectToVisible(upperClass2.react);
        }

        setVisible(true);
    }

    // you can skip this function but have a look if you eager to see how am I loaded image in the pane
     private void loadImage() {
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(imageFilePath);
            ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(imageFilePath.toString());
            JLabel jLabel = new JLabel(ii);
            jLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

                    int x = e.getX();
                    int y = e.getY();

                    jTextFieldX.setText(String.format("%d",x));
                    jTextFieldY.setText(String.format("%d",y));

                }
            });
            jScrollPaneImageScreen.setViewportView(jLabel);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SkeletonPreparing.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

   //init Component function was here

    private void jButtonOKActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

        if(upperClass2!=null){
            //other irrelevant processing deleted 

            //scrollbars states storing part
            upperClass2.verticalBar = jScrollPaneImageScreen.getVerticalScrollBar().getValue();
            upperClass2.horizontalBar = jScrollPaneImageScreen.getHorizontalScrollBar().getValue();
//            upperClass2.react = jScrollPaneImageScreen.getViewport().getViewRect();
            System.out.println("Stored: "+upperClass2.verticalBar+","+upperClass2.horizontalBar);
            upperClass2.setVisible(true);
        }
        dispose();
    }                                         
    //variable initializations were here
}
```

*BatchPaperEvaluation.java* class, from where I created the instance of the above class:

```
private void jButtonSubmitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    File[] filesToBeProcessed = new File(jTextFieldOMRFolderPath.getText()).listFiles(filter);
    for (File inputFile : filesToBeProcessed) {
        MultipleProcess dialog = new MultipleProcess(true, inputFile, null, this);
        //other processing
    }

    //further processing
}
```

#### Note:

- I have checked `int getVerticalScrollBarPolicy()`, which does not serve my work.

Comment: JScrollBar returns int value, more in API, and/or incl. visible rectangle from JViewport

Comment: I've checked the [API for JScrollPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html#api) and it might have some solutions for you. Namely [`int getVerticalScrollBarPolicy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#getVerticalScrollBarPolicy--)

Comment: @Trobbins Ow, I forgot to add it, I had checked it before, but the purpose of this function is different, about policy.

Comment: @mKorbel Can you have some link? I searched and don't found, that's why I asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `JScrollPane.getViewport().getViewRect()` to get the visible rectangle. You can restore this by doing `JScrollPane.getViewport().scrollRectToVisible(<saved rect>)`.

Comment: Unfortunately, It is not working for me, please see my class [here](https://gist.github.com/enamcse/a9962b7d95ec8a9827d4) and creating object from [here](https://gist.github.com/enamcse/6b4ab26bdc95e9ca9f30). First code is lengthy so, have a look on constructor, and `private void jButtonOKActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)` and I made second one short. your process is commented in the code, but ran it commenting the alternate solution. Please, tell me, if I did anything wrong.

Comment: Sorry manetsus, I can't see anything obviously wrong. But it's very har to tell what it might be without being able to run the code. Try to make a minimal program as the others suggest.

Comment: Forgot to say that the point of making a mcve usually is that you get it working and thereby can start looking at what the real cause of error is in the big program.

Comment: I made [this](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1syfxfex6a5q6p6/AAAoQOG3bL4dx84KTCMsmfwoa?dl=0) tiny NetBeans project for you to make understand my problem. It is very short. Just have some pictures in a folder and paste the folder path in the constructor of `ShowFrame.java`. Then run the program with the main of `Main.java` class.

Comment: manetsus: Thanks. Got the project running, except from the fact that the image folder you were refering to by path. But I substituted my own image folder. Try calling jScrollPaneImageScreen.getViewport().scrollRectToVisible(...) instead, worked for me. Not sure why though...

Comment: Thanks, it worked fine. I have edited in your answer. @AlexanderTorstling

Answer (score 2):

If you use [`scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollBar.html#getValue--), you can save that value when you close the pane.

Then, when you reload the pane, just use [`scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar.setValue(savedValue)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollBar.html#setValue-int-).

You would also do the same for the horizontal scroll bar as well.

I looked at the MCVE you put in the comments, I strongly doubt the problem is in the code you gave me, it's probably in the class that calls `new MultipleProcess`.

Comment: Unfortunately, It is not working for me. It can be my bad, but still I am trying.

Comment: @manetsus Can you [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32054441/edit) your question to show the code you're using? See: [mcve]

Comment: It would take time to make a mvce, but you can have a look on my class [here](https://gist.github.com/enamcse/a9962b7d95ec8a9827d4). Have a look in constructor and `private void jButtonOKActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)`. Remember, I am creating a new existence of this function every-time and always using `upperClass2` , you can see [here](https://gist.github.com/enamcse/6b4ab26bdc95e9ca9f30) where I have cut most of the irrelevant things. @durron597

Comment: @manetsus `It would take time to make a mvce,` - if you want help then take the time to create the MVCE. We are not here to debug your code for you. You have been given the appropriate method to use. The point of creating a MVCE is to understand the basic concept of using the method. Then once you get the MVCE working and understand the concept you can debug your own code to see what you are doing differently.

Comment: @camickr I never told that I would not do it, but as I am not that speedy, I have to take time. and no one told you to debug my code, just give me a working example, I would do the debugging myself.

Comment: @durron597 I have added the code as an edit in the question. I apologize, If I did not do it correctly as I am new to learn `mcve`, but it is interesting.

Comment: @durron597, I made [this](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1syfxfex6a5q6p6/AAAoQOG3bL4dx84KTCMsmfwoa?dl=0) tiny NetBeans project for you guys (your one is in comment) to make understand my problem. It is very short. Just have some pictures in a folder and paste the folder path in the constructor of `ShowFrame.java`. Then run the program with the main of `Main.java` class.

Comment: @manetsus Don't comment me, [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32054441/edit) your post to contain the code, do not link to an external netbeans project link.